# Console error in calling disk file program

Tags: java, ioexception

I am writing a program that calls a file location and file name and makes it into an String array. The program compiles but when it runs it comes back with console errors. I am new at java and I do not know how to troubleshoot these console errors or why they are happening. If someone could help me out that would be great. I marked with comments where the two errors are. the first error is in the main method and the other is in the bubblesort method.

EDIT:
This is the error I receive,

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at Assignment7.bubbleSort(Assignment7.java:63)
    at Assignment7.main(Assignment7.java:21)

and when I click on it they lead me to where I have pointed out below.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

public class program3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    String[] list2, targets, list1;
    list1 = getInput("C:\\Desktop\\input1.txt");    
    list2 = bubbleSort(list1);                      //Console error here
    targets = getInput("C:\\Desktop\\targets1.txt");

    double seqAvg = seqSearch(list1, targets);
    double binAvg = binSearch(list2, targets);
    System.out.println("Average number of searches for the seqeuntial search is " + seqAvg);
    System.out.println("Average number of searches for the binary search is " + binAvg);

}//end of main method

public static String[] getInput(String filename) throws IOException {
    String[] inputArr = new String[100];

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    int count = 0;
    while(in.hasNext()) { 
        if (count < 100){
            inputArr[count++] = in.next();
        } else {
            break;
        }

        }       
    in.close();
    return inputArr;

}// end getInput method



 //This method will sort the array and pass it onto a list.
  public static String[]bubbleSort(String[] inputArr) {

    String[] Array2 = inputArr.clone();

    for (int i = 0; i<Array2.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<Array2.length; j++)
        {
           if (Array2[i].compareTo(Array2[i+1]) > 0)  //Console error here
            {
                String temp = Array2[i];
                Array2[i] = Array2[j];
                Array2[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return Array2;

}// End of sort method.

//This method will do a sequential search on the list1
public static double seqSearch(String[] list1, String[] targets){
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < list1.length; j++)
          {
              for(String str:targets){
              if(list1[j].equalsIgnoreCase(str)){
                  return j;
              }
          }
             {
                return j;
             }
         }
         return -1;
       }

}//end of sequentialSearch method


//This method will do a binary search on the list   
public static int binSearch(String[] list1, String[] targets) {
       int lo = 0;
        int hi = list1.length - 1;
        int mid = -1;

        while( lo <= hi ) {
          mid = (lo+hi)/2;

          for(String str:targets){
          if(list1[mid].equalsIgnoreCase(str)){
              return mid;
          }

          hi = mid-1;


          } for(String str:targets){
          if(list1[mid].equalsIgnoreCase(str)){
              return mid;
          }
      }

            lo = mid+1;
           {
            return mid;
          }
        }
        return mid;
      }

}//End of program3
```

Comment: What is a "console error"? Please [edit] your post and include the complete stack trace.  Also _"calls a file location and file name and makes it into an String array"_ does not make sense. Please clarify.

Comment: *"C:\\Desktop"* This is not the usual path to the desktop. Have you created your own directory?

Answer (score 0):

You get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because in the bubbleSort method at this line:

```
if (Array2[i].compareTo(Array2[i+1]) > 0)
```

index i+1 is greater then the array length.
I suggest you to change the loop in the bubble sort method in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i<Array2.length; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j<Array2.length-1; j++)
  {
      if (Array2[j].compareTo(Array2[j+1]) > 0)
      {
        String temp = Array2[j];
        Array2[j] = Array2[j+1];
        Array2[j+1] = temp;
      }
   }
}
```